# How do I unnest list embeded in data.frame column?

Tags: r, dplyr, nested-lists, purrr

I'm new to working with nested lists, so I'm hoping the solution provided can also provide some commenting on the how.  I have a nested list that I scraped using `jsonlite`.  How do I take how to take the list data for all teams, and bind together into a single `data.frame`?  The list is setup below.  I copied one element of the list (for 1 team)

Here is the code I used to get to the list that I've pasted below.  I'm showing simply so that I can provide how the list is setup.

```
json <-
  url %>%
  fromJSON(simplifyDataFrame = T)


df <- json$body$rosters

# DF with each team showing up on it's own line, but nested lists in players
df_teams <- df$teams

# One teams worth of data 
JSON_list <- df_teams[1, ]
```

My list content is below.

```
JSON_list <- structure(list(
  projected_points = NA, long_abbr = "KE", lineup_status = "ok",
  short_name = "Kramerica", total_roster_salary = 22L, division = "",
  players = list(structure(list(
    firstname = c(
      "Jonathan", "Anthony"
    ), wildcards = structure(list(
      contract = c("1", "1"),
      salary = c("1", "21")
    ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
      NA,
      2L
    )), on_waivers = c(
      0L, 0L
    ), photo = c(
      "http://sports.cbsimg.net/images/baseball/mlb/players/170x170/1657581.png",
      "http://sports.cbsimg.net/images/baseball/mlb/players/170x170/1670417.png"
    ),
    eligible_for_offense_and_defense = c(0L, 0L),
    opponents = list(
      structure(list(
        game_id = c(
          "", ""
        ), weather_error = c(
          "Weather is not available for this game yet",
          "Weather is not available for this game yet"
        ),
        weather_icon_code = c(
          "", ""
        ), home_team = c("true", "true"),
        abbrev = c("OAK", "OAK"),
        time = c(
          1553803620L,
          1553911620L
        ),
        date = c(
          "20190328",
          "20190329"
        ), weather_icon_url = c(
          "", ""
        ), venue_type = c("", ""), game_abbr = c("", ""),
        weather = c("", ""), temperature = c(
          NA, NA
        )
      ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 2L)),
      structure(list(game_id = c("", "", ""), weather_error = c(
        "Weather is not available for this game yet",
        "Weather is not available for this game yet", "Weather is not available for this game yet"
      ), weather_icon_code = c("", "", ""), home_team = c(
        "true",
        "true", "true"
      ), abbrev = c("TEX", "TEX", "TEX"), time = c(
        1553803500L,
        1553990700L, 1554062700L
      ), date = c(
        "20190328", "20190330",
        "20190331"
      ), weather_icon_url = c("", "", ""), venue_type = c(
        "",
        "", ""
      ), game_abbr = c("", "", ""), weather = c(
        "", "",
        ""
      ), temperature = c(NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
        NA,
        3L
      ))
    ), icons = structure(list(
      headline = c(
        "Angels' Jonathan Lucroy: Inks deal with Angels",
        NA
      ),
      hot = c(NA, 1L),
      cold = c(1L, NA),
      injury = c(
        "Knee: Questionable for start of season",
        NA
      )
    ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 21L)), elias_id = c(
      "LUC758619", "RIZ253611"
    ), percentstarted = c(
      "48%", "97%"
    ),
    profile_link = c(
      "<a class='playerLink' aria-label=' Jonathan Lucroy C LAA' href='http://baseball.cbssports.com/players/playerpage/1657581'>Jonathan Lucroy</a> <span class=\"playerPositionAndTeam\">C | LAA</span> ",
      "<a class='playerLink' aria-label=' Anthony Rizzo 1B CHC' href='http://baseball.cbssports.com/players/playerpage/1670417'>Anthony Rizzo</a> <span class=\"playerPositionAndTeam\">1B | CHC</span>"
    ),
    id = c(
      "1657581", "1670417"
    ), pro_status = c(
      "A", "A"
    ), on_waivers_until = c(NA, NA), jersey = c("20", "44"),
    percentowned = c("61%", "99%"),
    pro_team = c(
      "LAA", "CHC"
    ), position = c(
      "C", "1B"
    ), lastname = c(
      "Lucroy", "Rizzo"
    ),
    roster_pos = c("C", "1B"),
    update_type = c("normal", "normal"),
    age = c(
      32L, 29L
    ), eligible = c(
      "C,U", "1B,U"
    ), is_locked = c(
      0L,
      0L
    ), bats = c(
      "R", "L"
    ), owned_by_team_id = c(
      12L, 12L
    ), ytd_points = c(
      0L, 0L
    ), roster_status = c(
      "A", "A"
    ), is_keeper = c(
      0L, 0L
    ), profile_url = c(
      "http://baseball.cbssports.com/players/playerpage/1657581",
      "http://baseball.cbssports.com/players/playerpage/1670417"
    ), fullname = c(
      "Jonathan Lucroy", "Anthony Rizzo"
    ), throws = c(
      "R",
      "L"
    ), headline = c(
      "Angels' Jonathan Lucroy: Inks deal with Angels",
      NA
    ), `starting-pitcher-today` = c(
      NA, "false"
    ), injury = c(NA, "Knee"), return = c(
      "Questionable for start of season",
      NA
    )
  ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 2L))),
  name = "Kramerica Enterprises", logo = "http://baseball.cbssports.com/images/team-logo/main-36x36.jpg",
  abbr = "KE", point = "20190328", id = "12", active_roster_salary = 22L,
  warning = structure(list(description = NA_character_), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")

# Desired table sample (does not include all columns)
tibble::tribble(
  ~projected_points, ~long_abbr, ~lineup_status, ~short_name, ~total_roster_salary, ~division,               ~name, ~logo, ~abbr,  ~point5, ~active_roster_salary,    ~id2, ~firstname, ~contract, ~salary,
                 NA,       "KE",           "ok", "Kramerica",                   22,        NA, "Biloxi Blackjacks",    NA,  "KE", 20190328,                    22, 1657581, "Jonathan",         1,       1
  )
```

The issue I'm running into is that the players column looks to be a nested `df`, and also has other nested `df` in it.  Specifically: "wildcards", "opponents" and "icons".  I am looking for a data frame that contains all of the columns.  For the nested lists, I'd like their content to show up as columns for that particular player.  I.E. Wildcards, create a column for "contract" and "salary".  Also, how would I bind the list together if I wanted to specifically choose columns from `JSON_list`  I.E. `"long_abbr"`, `"lineup_status"`, etc. from the and `"firstname"`, both `wildcard` columns, `"id"`, and some other from the `JSON_list$players`?

Comment: To make it easier for others to help you, I would provide the json for at least two records and then focus on just the problematic columns. Show the input structure and the desired output structure. This should help clean-up the question considerably.

Comment: Thanks Jason.  What do you mean provide the json for at least two records?  Should I clean up the example below to remove columns?  I'm not really sure about the best way to bind all of the elements together.

Answer (score 0):

You can isolate the list elements using `[[]]` and the columns using `[]` if you have a nested structure. If the number if rows are equal, you can directly make your dataframe using `cbind`

Let's make a reproducible example

Create 3 data frames of similar dimensions

```
 df1 <- data.frame(var1=c('a', 'b', 'c'), var2=c('d', 'e', 'f'), var3=1:3)
 df2 <- data.frame(var4=c('g', 'h', 'i'), var5=c('j', 'k', 'l'), var6=4:6)
 df3 <- data.frame(var7=c(6:8), var8=c('j', 'k', 'l'), var9=4:6)
```

Put the data frames in a nested list structure

```
 list <- list(df1,df2)
 nested.list <- list(list, df3)
```

Make a binded data frame made of var2, var6 and var7

```
binded.df <- cbind(nested.list[[1]][[1]][2],nested.list[[1]][[2]][3],nested.list[[2]][1])
```

Comment: I edited my answer with a reproducible example. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking a crack ePoQ.  I understand the concept of how to bind nested lists.  My issue is that I'm trying to take all of the columns within the nested column (some of them are nested df) and bind to a single list.  Any chance you can review my initial question?